# PHP find keywords in XML feed - preg_match_all

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I'm loading in a rss feed in XML. I am then attempting to search the RSS feed for keywords. I then need to it email myself with a notification that it found these key words and their contents.

Example i have:

```
$keywords = "iphone|ipad|ipod";

$rss = simplexml_load_file("http://myfeed.com/news?format=xml");
foreach ($rss->entry as $i)
{
  //need to check the title tag for the keywords
  //email myself a notification with the keywords found 
}
```

UPDATE
Ok i have the following which is part working:

```
    function getPartsWithRegex($text, $regex){
    preg_match_all($regex, $text, $array);
    return $array[0];
}

$keywords = "LLC|socks";

$rss = simplexml_load_file("http://feeds.myfeed.com/iphoneapps-news?format=xml");

$text = "Downcast - Jamawkinaw Enterprises LLC";
$regex = "/$keywords/i";


foreach ($rss->entry as $i)
{
$title = (string)$i->title;
$productNumbers = getPartsWithRegex($text, $regex);
}


if(count($productNumbers) > 0){
    foreach($productNumbers as $productNumber){
        echo $productNumber . '<br />';
    }
}
else {
    echo "Nothing found.";
}
```

This works when i pass $productNumbers = getPartsWithRegex($text, $regex); However, when i pass $title which has the value of $i->title it doesnt work. Even though when i echo out the value of $title to the browser it renders as: Downcast - Jamawkinaw Enterprises LLC

So to clarify when i manually enter and pass a string it works correct. However, when i pass the value from the XML which is read it doesnt. I've tried converting to string but that doesnt work.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Something like preg_match_all("/[iphone|ipad|ipod]/i", $i=>getAttribute("title"), $matches);

Comment: It seems you don't need regex; Is this acceptable: http://3v4l.org/Qnc9S ?